# Read numbers in file and find Median C

Tags: c

I am constructing a C program which prints Fibonacci numbers into a file and finds the median.

The output I am getting is a very large and incorrect number. Any insight would be great.

Median Function C

```
   int findMedian(FILE *file, int size)
   {
      int medianPos, medianVal, readVal, count;
      medianPos = (size / 2);
      count = 0;

      while(fscanf(file,"%d", &readVal)==1)
      {
         if(medianPos == count)
         {
            medianVal = readVal;
         }
         if ((medianPos += 1) == count)
         {
            if(size % 2) //This means that it is even
            {

            }
            else
            {
               medianVal += readVal;
               medianVal /= 2;
            }
         }
         count++;
      }
      return medianVal;
   }
```

File

```
1 1 2 3 
5 8 13 21 
34 55 89 144 
233 377 610 987 
1597 2584 4181 6765
```

Output

```
The Fibonacci median: -1576638118
```

Function Call

```
median = findMedian(Fibonacci, size);
```

Comment: well I have no idea if this is the whole problem, but `size % 2` will be `0` for even numbers, so your logic is backwards there.

Comment: `if ((medianPos += 1) == count)` I think this line has the problem. `medianPos += 1` translates to `medianPos = medianPos +1`. So `medianPos`  will keep on incremeting.

Comment: Why do you need to continue reading when you get to the median value? (looks like you already know how many numbers are in the file when you use `size`)

Comment: `count` is an *uninitialised variable*. Please enable compiler warnings.

Comment: You forgot to initialize some of your variables.  BTW: this sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment -- it's frowned upon to ask those on SO...

Comment: Got it. I will fix count and try it. Ayush I believe you are correct that could be a source of some issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'count' variable is not initialized. So it is possible that your if conditions will not be met and your medianVal remain uninitialized too.

Comment: Thanks for the input Luci! I have initialized count to 0 and the issue still remains. (Added edit above)

Comment: Did you initialized medianVal  too, Otherwise it is possible that second condition to be met first and then you add a value to an unitialized value